# what is the drwsrwsrwx?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

why cant I change this back to 775 ...when i try it stays like this drwsrwsr-x

what is the s and why is it not drwxrwxr-x

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://serverfault.com/questions/238962/what-is-the-drwsrwsrwx).

Answer (score 3):

The 's's mean "Set User ID" and "Set Group ID". In directories, the first "s" has no meaning. The second one (Set Group ID) means that new files created in the directory will have the same group as the directory itself. New subdirectories will have the same group AND will inherit the same "s" flag.

Answer (score 1):

The 's' you are seeing in the "execute" position in the user and group column are the SetUID (Set User ID on Execution) and SetGID (Set Group ID on execution) bits.

Unix file permissions are actually a 4-digit octal number SUGO

S controls the SetUID (4), SetGID (2) and "Sticky" (1) bits
U controls Read(4)/Write(2)/Execute(1) bits for the file owner
G controls the Read/Write/Execute bits for the file's group
O controls the Read/Write/Execute bits for everyone else.

You can remove the setuid bits from your directory with chmod ug-s directory, if there are subdirectory included use -R option.